# Не запускается Eclipse на Mac OSX

Tags: java, eclipse

Пытаюсь запустить Eclipse, появляется окно ошибки, которое перенаправляет меня в лог ошибки. При открытии лога появляется следующая ошибка. В чём ошибка и как исправить?

[image: В логе вот такая ошибка]

Comment: mac os x leopard?

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=207782

Comment: укажите версию операционной системы и версию программы

Comment: OS: 10.9.5, версия Eclipse и Java последняя.